# How to formulate this constrained optimization in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, constraints

I got this constrained function and I'm trying to solve it using MATLAB.

```
1/2x^T XAXx:IIxII^2=1
```

Where `T` for transpose `A` is a symmetric nxn matrix and `X` is the diagonal matrix with element `x_i`. Also, `IIxII` denotes the Euclidean norm of a vector `x`.

I would like to know how to formulate this constrained function in Matlab.

Comment: This is unclear. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmincon`. Suppose that you have a 2-dimensional problem to solve.

Then let's create your symmetric matrix A :

```
R = rand(2,2);
A = 0.5 * (R + R');
```

Then your objective function can be written as :

```
fun = @(x) 0.5 * diag([x(1) 0 ; 0 x(2)])' * [x(1) 0 ; 0 x(2)] * A * [x(1) 0 ; 0 x(2)] * diag([x(1) 0 ; 0 x(2)]);
```

You also need to set your equality constraints :

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
c = [];             % Compute nonlinear inequalities at x.
ceq = x' * x - 1;   % Compute nonlinear equalities at x.
end
```

Finally, you can solve your problem with initial condition `x0` :

```
x0 = [0.3,0.7];
sol = fmincon(fun,x0, [], [], [], [], [], [], @mycon)
```

In the example above, the problem may not be suited for the use of fmincon. Try it out with your matrix A first. Otherwise, try `fminsearch`.